# CSS - Footer is cutting off itself on other pages of website with a global footer

Tags: html, css

This website is being made with a back-end web to print service called Zoo Printing. The client I work for does not like their original design so I'm being hired to re-design it with their development team that handles the back-end. We can't find the reason why the footer (Which is global) is getting cut off on every other page except the front-page. Their developers are blaming my code, and will not tell me where the problem is coming from. Can one of you inspect my code, and tell me what would be causing this?

The website is [Advanced Litho](http://www.advancedlitho.com).

The front page is looking perfect for the footer, but it's when you go to another page you will see how it's cut off at the bottom.

```
    <div id="footer">
    <div class="content_width"> 
        <h1>The Largest Selection of Offset & Digital Products in the Market Today</h1>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/AdvancedLithoPrinting" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.offsetprinting.com/img/custom_images/facebook_icon.png" /></a> <!-- Facebook Link -->
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/pub/advanced-litho-printing-bindery/42/556/a54" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.offsetprinting.com/img/custom_images/linkdin_icon.png" /></a> <!-- Linkdin Link -->
            <a href="x"><img src="http://www.offsetprinting.com/img/custom_images/instagram_icon.png" target="_blank" /></a> <!-- Instragram Link -->

        <ul> <!-- Footer Navigation Menu -->
            <li><a href="http://www.offsetprinting.com/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.offsetprinting.com/account/contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://secure.offsetprinting.com/account/estimate">Quotes</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.offsetprinting.com/helpcenter">Help Center</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://secure.offsetprinting.com/samples">Samples</a></li>
        </ul>

        </div>

        <div id="terms_policy">
            <a href="http://www.offsetprinting.com/pages/terms-and-conditions" target="_blank">TERMS & CONDITIONS</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="http://www.offsetprinting.com/pages/privacy-policy" target="_blank">PRIVACY POLICY</a>
        </div>


</div>  <!-- End of Footer -->

<div id="copyright"> <!-- Copy Right at Lower of Footer -->
    <h4>© <a href="www.advancedlitho.com">2015 Advanced Litho Printing & Bindery</a> + 20996 Bake Parkway, Suite 112 + Lake Forest CA 92630-2169 + (949) 215-9060 + Fax (949) 215-9181</h4> 
 </div>

    #terms_policy  {
    margin:0px auto;
    width:259px;
    color:#FFF;
}
#terms_policy a {
    color:#FFF; 
}

#terms_policy a:hover {
    color:red;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#footer {
    height:190px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    clear: both;
    background-color:#343232;
}

#footer .content_width {
    height:150px;
    background-color:#343232;
    padding-top: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333333;
}
#copyright {
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    clear:both;
    height:47px;
    background-color:#cec41e;
}
#copyright h4 {
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */   
}
#copyright a {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#copyright a:hover {
    color:red;  
}   
#footer h1 {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#FFF;
}
#footer img {
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-right:5px;   
    height:40px;
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration:0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration:0.8s;
    transition-duration:0.8s;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#footer img:hover  {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
    transform:rotate(360deg);
}  
#footer li {
    display:inline-block;
    border-right:1px solid #FFF;
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0 8px;
}
#footer li:nth-child(1) {
    border-left:1px solid #FFF;

}
#footer ul {
    margin-left:250px;
}
#footer li a {
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
    font-size:18px; 
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: Like @caitilin M mentioned this is coming from offsetprinting.com main.css, 
because advancedlitho is being displayed through an iframe you will have to change the main.css in the offsetprinting.com directory. Simply remove the position: absolute and it is looking better.

Comment: This is the crazy part. I added that attribute only because Zoo Printing is choosing to keep their old navigation menu in my code but commented out. If i remove this CSS the site will now look like this. It has a huuuuge white space right below my CSS sideshow, and right above the footer. www.Advancedlitho.com. They told me if i wanted to remove it i can do so with CSS, but they refuse to remove it them selfs. Even though their code is commented out it's still messing up my DOM. Do you know a way i can remove this block of code without messing up the footer?

Answer (score 0):

This code in your main.css is causing it to not show up:

```
body > div:nth-child(4) { /*Removes The Invisible Navigation*/
    position:absolute;
    left: -1000px;  
}
```

Comment: This is the crazy part. I added that attribute only because Zoo Printing is choosing to keep their old navigation menu in my code but commented out. If i remove this CSS the site will now look like this. It has a huuuuge white space right below my CSS sideshow, and right above the footer. www.Advancedlitho.com. They told me if i wanted to remove it i can do so with CSS, but they refuse to remove it them selfs. Even though their code is commented out it's still messing up my DOM. Do you know a way i can remove this block of code without messing up the footer?